# Datatable does not work in Laravel 9 & Vite; Error jQuery is not defined

Tags: laravel, datatable, laravel-8, vite, laravel-9

I am trying to add datatable in my Laravel 9 project (I use Vite).

I noticed it doesn't work because I'm getting these two errors:

First error:

> $ is not defined

Second error:

> jQuery is not defined

This is my complete code:

*bootstrap.js*

```
try {
    window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap');
    require('datatables.net');
} catch (e) {}
```

*app.js*

```
import './../../node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables';
```

*view*

```
<table id="tableclient" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover sizethtd">
            <tr>
                <th class="">Name</th>
                <th class="">Email</th>
                <th class="">Address</th>
                <th class="">Action</th>
            </tr>
            @foreach ($clients as $client)
            <tr>
                <td><a href="{{route('client.show' , compact('client'))}}" class="text-muted fw-bold paddingLink">{{ $client->name }}</a></td>
                <td class=""><a href= "mailto:{{ $client->email }}" class="text-muted paddingLink fw-bold">{{ $client->email }}</a></td>    
                <td class="">{{ $client->address }}</td>
                <td>                     
                <a class="btn btn-info" href="{{route('project.create', compact('client'))}}">Add</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </table>

<script>

        $(function () {
            $('#tableclient').DataTable({
                processing: true,
                serverSide: false
            });
        });

    </script>
```

*vite.cofig.js*

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

Could anyone kindly help me?

**UPDATE**

I installed jquery via the command

```
npm i jquery
```

and in app.js I imported, along with datatable, the following line:

```
import './../../node_modules/jquery/src/css';
```

The error still continues to exist

Answer (score 0):

You're just missing jQuery. There's various ways to add jQuery,one quick way but not idael way is to add by cdn

`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script`>

https://releases.jquery.com/

Comment: i don't use cdn in my project. how can i add it without these?

Comment: These two answers should suffice, moreover jQuery is just a js file, if you don't want to use cdn you can simply download the file, put it in your public folder and point to it in your template or view blade file ```<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('yourJQueryFileNameHere.js')}}"></script>``` No biggie, problem solved.  More info here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vite/laravel-vite-jquery

Comment: this thing you said I'm not understanding. That is script ... because in the file you sent me with it exists

Comment: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js right click this link, save it as a file and put it in you folder called public. Then at the top of your blade file add ```<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('jquery-3.6.0.min.js')}}"></script>```    or go to https://releases.jquery.com/ and right click and download jQuery Core 3.6.0 - minified (it's the same file I linked above). jQuery is just a javascript file.

Comment: Tried but it still doesn't work

Comment: Ok you'll need start from the beginning, I suggest you first use the CDN just to see where you problem exists. That CDN link should be on the page you're using datables. Then once that works, watch some tutorials on how to download and point to files from within your blade. Sorry not much more I can tell you. $ is not defined means you're trying to use a jQuery method but the page doesn't have jQuery loaded. You just need to learn how to add jQuery. Unfortunately our efforts failed, there's many articles and tutorials online about adding jQuery, just need to find one that's clear for you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing the `Jquery` CDN link.

You may use

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Or By Installing it manually, by:

```bash
npm install jquery
```

or

```bash
yarn add jquery
```

Inside your `bootstrap.js` or `app.js` use

```js
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery')
```

Then require `js/app.js` inside your app.

Comment: without cdn how can i use it? I work all with import

Comment: I have updated my question. Read it please

Comment: I gave you the option, if you are not using the CDN, read carefully please.

Comment: everything you wrote I did. maybe the imports are wrong?

Comment: Use `require` instead of `import`, and your issue, it's not with `import` it's your application missing jQuery dependencies, so follow the answer above, and you will find your solution.

Comment: done but it doesn't work anyway. Always the same mistakes

Comment: I also receive `require is not defined`